# React and JS closure issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

### Background of the problem

I have a simple "Ticker" class that can hold a single callback, and execute that callback each ~1s via  `setInterval` The code is as follows.

```
class Ticker{
  listner = null;
  
  constructor(){
    setInterval(this.excuteCallbackInterval, 1000)
  }

  addListner(callback){
     this.listner = callback
  }

  excuteCallbackInterval = () => {
    if(this.listner){
       this.listner();
    }else {
      console.log("no listner registered");
    } 
  }
}
```

I have a `React Functional Component` in a nother file, that instantiates a Ticker Object, at class level(I.E outside the functional component) but inside the same file. Here's the code for that component. (some parts are removed to make it concise)

```
.
.
.
const ticker = new Ticker()

// react component.
function TimerDuration({ changingValue }) {

  const unsubscribe = useRef(null)
  

  function runEachSecond() {
    console.log('inside runEachSecond', changingValue)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    unsubscribe.current = ticker.addListener(runEachSecond)
    // Cleanup
    return () => {
      try {
        unsubscribe.current()
      } catch (err) {
        // Do nothing
      }
    }
   }, [])

  return (
    <Text>
      {changingValue}
    </Text>
  )
}
```

### Problem

My problem is that when the timer `TimerDuration` renders initially `changingValue` painted on the screen and `changingValue` inside `excuteCallbackInterval` is the same,

But when the `changingValue` prop is updated, that updated value is **not** reflected inside `excuteCallbackInterval` but the change is reflected in the value painted on the screen.

### Solution.

My solution was (in a way by instinct) was to store the value of `changingValue` in a ref and update it inside a second `useEffect` that runs each time. Might not be the ideal one hence this question.

### Question

My question is why am I seeing this behavior? `runEachSecond` is evaluated with each prop update. And it's able to access `changingValue` because it's in its parent scope. `excuteCallbackInterval` function within the `Ticker` also has access to `changingValue` because of the closure. But why does the update not reflect within `excuteCallbackInterval`? Also is there a better way to solve this issue?

Comment: `ticker.addListener()` does not return an unsubscribe function.

Comment: Did you expect `ticker.addListener(runEachSecond)` to be called again when the `changingValue` prop changes?

Comment: @Bergi yes the unsubscribe code is missing. And as for the second question, No just want it to be subscribed after mounting, and unsubscribed when unmounting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to unsubscribe and subscribe again every time `changingValue` change. Or, said in another way: you want to update the `ticker`'s callback to prevent it from going stale.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    function runEachSecond() {
      console.log('inside runEachSecond', changingValue)
    }

    const unsubscribe = ticker.addListener(runEachSecond)
    // Cleanup
    return () => {
      try {
        unsubscribe()
      } catch (err) {
        // Do nothing
      }
    }
   }, [changingValue]) //  see changingValue in the deps
```

Why do you need to do this? Right now, your component does something like this:

- mount
- `runEachSecond` is created (instance #1)
- subscribe to Ticker, pass `runEachSecond` #1
- `changingValue` prop get update
- `runEachSecond` is created again (instance #2)
- `Ticker` still hold a reference of `runEachSecond` #1

After adding `changingValue` in the deps of the useEffect:

- mount
- `runEachSecond` is created (instance #1)
- subscribe to Ticker, pass `runEachSecond` #1
- `changingValue` prop get update
- `runEachSecond` is created again (instance #2)
- `Ticker` unsubscribe from  `runEachSecond` #1
- `Ticker` subscribe again, but to `runEachSecond` #2

Answer (score 2):

> My question is why am I seeing this behavior? `runEachSecond` is evaluated with each prop update.

No, it's not updated. In React, all variables stay constant. A *new* `runEachSecond` function is created every time the `TimerDuration` function component is rendered, and that *new* function would close over the new `changingValue` parameter.

However, `runEachSecond` is only used in the effect (in `ticker.addListener(runEachSecond)`), which runs only once (when the component is mounted). The `ticker` will store only the first of the many `runEachSecond` functions, and it will never change (`addListener` is not called again), and that first function still closes over the first `changingValue`.

> I just want it to be subscribed after mounting, and unsubscribed when unmounting.

In that case, you should store the `changingValue` in the ref, and then refer to that ref (and its future values) from the ticker listener function. The ref for the `unsubscribe` function returned by `addListener` is unnecessary.

```
function TimerDuration({ changingValue }) {
  const value = useRef(null);
  value.current = changingValue;
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = ticker.addListener(function runEachSecond() {
      console.log('inside runEachSecond', value.current);
//                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    });
    // Cleanup
    return () => {
      try {
        unsubscribe();
      } catch (err) {
        // Do nothing
      }
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <Text>
      {changingValue}
    </Text>
  )
}
```